# R Studio not responding to the names() command

Tags: r

I am writing the following below. R studio would send an error message:

> Error: unexpected input in "names(mancova)= c(�

in resonse to the line where I give new names to the columns:

`names(mancova)= c(“GPID”, “Precomp”, Postcomp”, “Posthior”)`

Here is the full code:

```
install.packages("MASS")
install.packages("car")
install.packages("psych")
install.packages("Rcpp")
library(MASS)
library (car)
library(psych)
group1 = matrix(c(1,15,17,3,1,10,6,3,1,13,13,1,1,14,14,8,1,12, 12, 3, 1, 10, 9, 9,1,12,12,3,1,8,9,12,1,12,15,3,1,8,10,8,1,12,13,1,1,7,11,10,1,12,16,1,1,9,12,2,1,12,14,8), nrow=15,ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
group2=matrix(c(2,9,9,3,2,13,19,5,2,13,16,11,2,6,7,18,2,10,11,15,2,6,9,9,2,16,20,8,2,9,15,6,2,10,8,9,2,8,10,3,2,13,16,12,2,12,17,20,2,11,18,12,2,14,18,16),nrow=14,ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)
mancova = data.frame(rbind(group1, group2))
names(mancova)= c(“GPID”, “Precomp”, Postcomp”, “Posthior”)
attach(mancova)
mancova
options(scipen=999)
outcome = cbind(mancova$Postcomp, mancova$Posthior)
model = manova(outcome~GPID+Precomp+GPID*Precomp, data=mancova)
summary(model, test=“Wilks”, type=“III”)
factor(GPID)
modelA = aov(Postcomp~Precomp+GPID, data=mancova)
summary(modelA, type=“III”)
library(effects)
adjmeanA = effect(“GPID”, modelA, se=TRUE,xlevels=2)
summary(adjmeanA)
adjmeanA$se
```

Comment: You appear to be using curly quotes. `“` instead of `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Its written in the error itself:

> Error: unexpected input in "names(mancova)= c(�

The last symbol is unknown to R, which is an italic/cursive version of the quotes. " " is defined/valid. *" "* is not.

Comment: @minnin54 Consider accepting the answer (tap the tick mark below the votes) if it solved your issue!